# Need xslt stylesheet to transform from below input xml to output xml

Tags: xml, xslt

Need to compare the value of 
`info/targetAudienceInfo/labelLocaleTextID` and `info/languageTranslation/localeTextID`, if it matches then need to display the value of respective languageTranslation/localeText under the `<label>` tag instead of `<xmlTag>`.

Similarly need to compare the value of `info/targetAudienceInfo/standAloneLabelLocaleTextID` and `info/languageTranslation/localeTextID`, if it matches then need to display the value of respective `languageTranslation/localeTex`t under the `<standAloneLabel>` tag instead of `<xmlTag>` using xslt.

Below is the input xml:

```
<info>
  <xmlTag>sender</xmlTag>
  <displayOrder>103</displayOrder>
  <targetAudienceInfo>
     <targetAudienceCode>SERVE</targetAudienceCode>
     <labelLocaleTextID>417</labelLocaleTextID>
     <standAloneLabelLocaleTextID>404</standAloneLabelLocaleTextID>
  </targetAudienceInfo>
  <languageTranslation>
     <localeTextID>417</localeTextID>
     <languageISOCode>ENGLISH</languageISOCode>
     <languageLocaleID>en-US</languageLocaleID>
     <localeText>Sender1</localeText>
  </languageTranslation>
  <languageTranslation>
     <localeTextID>404</localeTextID>
     <languageISOCode>ENGLISH</languageISOCode>
     <languageLocaleID>en-US</languageLocaleID>
     <localeText>Sender2</localeText>
  </languageTranslation>
```

Below is the expected output xml:

```
<info>
  <label>Sender1</label>
  <standAloneLabel>Sender2</standAloneLabel>
  <displayOrder>103</displayOrder>
  <targetAudienceInfo>
     <targetAudienceCode>SERVE</targetAudienceCode>
     <labelLocaleTextID>417</labelLocaleTextID>
     <standAloneLabelLocaleTextID>404</standAloneLabelLocaleTextID>
  </targetAudienceInfo>
  <languageTranslation>
     <localeTextID>417</localeTextID>
     <languageISOCode>ENGLISH</languageISOCode>
     <languageLocaleID>en-US</languageLocaleID>
     <localeText>Sender1</localeText>
  </languageTranslation>
  <languageTranslation>
     <localeTextID>404</localeTextID>
     <languageISOCode>ENGLISH</languageISOCode>
     <languageLocaleID>en-US</languageLocaleID>
     <localeText>Sender2</localeText>
  </languageTranslation>
 </info>
```

Comment: "*if it matches then need to display the value of ..*" And if it doesn't?

Comment: Sorry I missed to update on that part. In the input xml if xml tag is present then defenitely targetAudienceInfo and languageTranslation will be present and the whole <info> is repeating. The template given by you below is good. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following stylesheet will produce the expected result when applied to your input example. You did not say what should happen if there's no match, or if there's more than one match.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="trans" match="languageTranslation" use="localeTextID" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xmlTag">
    <label>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('trans', ../targetAudienceInfo/labelLocaleTextID)/localeText" />
    </label>
    <standAloneLabel>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('trans', ../targetAudienceInfo/standAloneLabelLocaleTextID)/localeText" />
    </standAloneLabel>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```